# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError when joining and merging parent model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) and [Will Paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate). I'm trying to compare the distance between a Users address and the kids moms addresses. Here are my models:

```
class User
 has_many :kids
 geocoded_by :address
end

class Kid
  belongs_to :mom
  belongs_to :dad
end

class Mom
  has_many :kids
  has_many :dads, through: :kids
  geocoded_by :address
end

class Dad
  has_many :kids
  has_many :moms, through: :kids
end
```

And than how I try to get this to work:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_user_location

  private

  def set_user_location
    if signed_in?
      @user_location = current_user.address
    end
  end
end

class DadsController

def show
  @dad = Dad.find(params[:id])
  @kids = @dad.kids.joins(:mom).merge(Mom.near(@user_location, 100)).order(name: :asc, created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
end
```

Now with all of this. I run into the error:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError - missing attribute: birthday:
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in read_attribute'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:94:in `fetch'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:94:in `block in read_attribute'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:84:in `fetch'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:84:in `read_attribute'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:59:in `__temp__57e69647'
  app/views/dads/show.html.erb:27:in `block in _app_views_dads_show_html_erb__397094631_92677670'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `each'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `each'
............
```

If I remove `kid.birthday` from the loop, than it will say the next attribute is the problem until I have no attributes left on my **dads/show.html.erb**.

```
<% @kids.each do |kid| %>
   <%= kid.birthday %>
   <%= kid.name %>
   <% if kid.upkeep.present? %>
     <%= kid.upkeep %>
     <%= kid.upkeep_size %> 
   <% end %>      
   <%= kid.age %>
   <%= kid.favorite_color %>
<% end %>
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: Post your `show.html.erb`

Comment: @Pavan OK, it's done.

Comment: How does the DB-struct look for "kid" table?

Did you perhaps forget to run rake db:migrate?

Comment: @gernberg If I turn the method into `@kids = @dad.kids.order(name: :asc, created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)` it works. My database Kid table has fake data so the migration is correct.

Comment: That query didn't include the "birthday" - are you certain you have that field in your db?

Comment: @gernberg Yes, I am. The problem lies in the `show` view though. If I remove birthday it just goes to saying `missing attribute: name, upkeep, etc.`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're merging kids with moms when you do:

```
.merge(Mom.near(@user_location, 100))
```

So, besides `Kid` objects, `@kids` will also contain `Mom` objects and those `Mom` objects don't have the attributes you expect. You can use `@kids.inspect` for debugging.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same thing but now I'm not sure how I would correct this.

Comment: @user2784630 added a suggestion how to fix this.

Comment: I can't start from the Mom because of the application design. It has to go through the dad. I tried the above but it returns an ActiveRecord Relation error that `kids` is undefined. I also tried using `includes(:kids)` on my other scope but it causes everything to go `NULL`.

Comment: The problem with my update is that `Mom.near` returns a collection, so you can't just call `.kids` on it. I'll think about another solution.